# Rails Datagrid - NoMethodError when trying to create datagrid form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datagrid, rubygems

Getting a NoMethodError when trying to do the following in your view with datagrid-

```
<%= datagrid_form_for  @foods_grid %>
```

Which is strange because the datagrid itself is tested and working fine-

```
<%= datagrid_table @foods_grid %>
```

The error details will say something like...

```
undefined method `foods_grids_path' for ...
```

And reference the _form partial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: You need to manually pass in the path that you're using to display the datagrid, like so -

```
<%= datagrid_form_for  @foods_grid, :method => :get, :url => foods_path %>
```

They don't mention these parameters in the tutorial!